# How may one retain backups on Autonomous Database (on Shared Infrastructure) for longer than 60 days?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

ADB (shared) provides the ability to take manual backups. According to the documentation, the retention time for manual created backups is 60 days, just like the automatic point in time back-ups.

How can a customer keep backups or a snapshot copy of their data for significantly longer, for auditing or analysis purposes?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you cannot length the backup retention period. However, you may take exports directly to your object store bucket of the [full database with datapump](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/export-data-other-database-dp.html#GUID-AB5F3773-EAD3-4E49-963D-69E8ECFBF116), export whole schemas using the [DBMS_DATAPUMP package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-5AAC848B-5A2B-4FD1-97ED-D3A048263118.htm#SUTIL977) or export tables, or the output of query, to using [DBMS_CLOUD.EXPORT_DATA](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/export-data-select.html#GUID-7DAB00F6-65B8-4678-B222-7939001A3469).

For an even simpler but less cost-efficient method, you may also clone your database, keep it as a copy in a stopped state and open it when needed.

Here's a sample for using datapump (19.9 or above for using the credential parameter) to export to the object store (linked above), to export your full database to the Oracle Cloud object store. The dumpfile path is your Oracle object store URL. You will need to create have a credential object for object store access, as described in the export [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/export-data-object-store-dp-new.html#GUID-7EE2B6BF-5DF3-43E7-8CA3-1FE5DC13FA1D).

```
expdp admin/password@db2020adb_high \
     filesize=5GB \
     credential=def_cred_name \
     dumpfile=https://objectstorage.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/n/namespace-string/b/bucketname/o/exp%U.dmp \
     parallel=16 \
     encryption_pwd_prompt=yes \
     logfile=export.log \
     directory=data_pump_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Autonomous database now has an option to take backups for extended periods of time. The ADB cloud console has a button called "Create long-term Backup" that allows you to take backups that are longer than the default 60 days. https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/post/long-term-backups-autonomous-database